# Select one random item from each list nested in a list, different between them, and generate a list n times (RESAMPLING)

Tags: python, random, sublist, resampling

I have a txt file with genecodes separated by tab similar to this structure:

```
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111555 
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111222  
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000333555
```

and I want to create a list with **selecting from each row one item randomly** and selected items must be **DIFFERENT BETWEEN THEM**. At the end I want to repeat the process n times in order to obtain an output file with this structure:

```
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111222 ENSG00000333555
ENSG00000111555 ENSG00000111222 ENSG00000333555
ENSG00000111555 ENSG00000111222 ENSG00000111111
...
```

(each row correspond to each generated list of random items)
. At the moment I have this script:
where: **all_cand** is the txt input file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import random
from itertools
import numpy as np
def rand_cand (all_cand):
    cand_list= []
    main_list = []
    cand_file= open(all_cand, "r")
    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 10):
        for line in cand_file:
            cand_rows = line.split()
            cand_list.append(cand_rows)

        for item in cand_list:
            aux_old = np.random.choice(item, replace=False)
            if not aux_old in main_list:
                main_list.append(aux_old)
            else:
                aux_new = np.random.choice(item, replace=False)
                main_list.append(aux_new)
    print(main_list)
```

Related to my script, every generated list contains repetitions and I think that is due to the *If loop*. I try to compare every item that is going to be appended to the list to those which have already stored but it fails ... so one of my wrong outputs are:

```
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111222
ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111
ENSG00000111555 ENSG00000111111 ENSG00000111111
...
```

Thanks beforehand!, I hope to be clear with the explanation of my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it yet, but this should do it

```
import csv
import itertools
import random

with open('file.txt') as infile:
    data = list(csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'))

answer = []
combos = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([0,1,2,3], 3))
for _ in range(n):
    selection = []
    while len(set(selection)) != 3:
        inds = random.choice(combos)
        rows = random.sample(data, 3)
        selection = [row[i] for i,row in zip(inds, rows)]
    answer.append(selection)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already used your script but It doesn't give any result ...

Comment: @Gaferolo: there was a tiny bug in there. It's fixed now. Check it out!

Comment: I have already changed the tiny bug but It still does not work. have you tested it?

Comment: @Gaferolo: I could take another look if you could post a larger sample of the input text file

Comment: my input larger sample file is the same as the example I post, but with 24 lines and each row have different number of gene codes (from 18 to 300 of gene codes). I can't post the real input because the size.

Comment: @Gaferolo: Are you getting an error, or is the output incorrect?

Comment: When I run the script It does not give me any output and it neither gives me an error @inspectorG4dget

Comment: Add `print(answer)` to the end of the script, if you want it to print the results to screen

Comment: I have already included the print, but now I find the problematic stuff, It was that I was using the example input file and It last so much because the probability of taking the repeated gene code (ENSG00000111111) is higher when the selection is randomly. Now I am trying with less repetitions and it takes just seconds to give the output. So, Now it is solved. Thanks a lot!